# VBA userform duplicate validation

Tags: excel, vba, forms, duplicates

im only a week into VBA and its an awesome thing to use.

im currently working on a login register for work and im stuck on duplicate validation base on "username" column as its the only unique field.

the userform will still allow me to add duplicate entries with the same username in the username column

```
Function ValidateEntries() As Boolean

ValidateEntries = True

Dim iUsername As Variant

Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print")

iLastName = frmFORM.txtLast.Value

With frmFORM

    'Default Color
    
    .txtLast.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtFirst.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtUser.BackColor = vbWhite
    .cmbStatus.BackColor = vbWhite
    .cmbZone.BackColor = vbWhite
    .cmbRole.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtPhone.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtPrimaryEmail.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtLocation.BackColor = vbWhite
    .cmbRequestedBy.BackColor = vbWhite
    '--------------------------------
    
    If Trim(.txtLast.Value) = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "Please enter Last Name.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Last Name"
        ValidateEntries = False
        .txtLast.BackColor = vbRed
        .txtLast.SetFocus
        Exit Function
        
    End If

    'Validating Duplicate Entries
    
    If Not sh.Range("B:B").Find(what:=iLastName, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        
        MsgBox "Duplicate Last Name found.", vbOKOnly + 
     vbInformation, "Last Name"
        ValidateEntries = False
        .txtLast.BackColor = vbRed
        .txtLast.SetFocus
        Exit Function
    
    End If
    
    If Trim(.txtFirst.Value) = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "Please enter First Name.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, 
     "First Name"
        ValidateEntries = False
        .txtFirst.BackColor = vbRed
        .txtFirst.SetFocus
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    If Trim(.txtUser.Value) = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "Please enter Username.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, 
      "Username"
        ValidateEntries = False
        .txtUser.BackColor = vbRed
        .txtUser.SetFocus
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    
    If Trim(.cmbStatus.Value) = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "Please select Status from drop-down.", vbOKOnly + 
      vbInformation, "Status"
        ValidateEntries = False
        .cmbStatus.BackColor = vbRed
        .cmbStatus.SetFocus
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    If Trim(.cmbZone.Value) = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "Please select Zone from drop-down.", vbOKOnly + 
       vbInformation, "Zone"
        ValidateEntries = False
        .cmbZone.BackColor = vbRed
        .cmbZone.SetFocus
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    If Trim(.cmbRole.Value) = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "Please select Role from drop-down.", vbOKOnly +                   
    vbInformation, "Role"
        ValidateEntries = False
        .cmbRole.BackColor = vbRed
        .cmbRole.SetFocus
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    
     If Trim(.txtPhone.Value) = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "Please enter a Phone Name.", vbOKOnly + 
     vbInformation, "Phone"
        ValidateEntries = False
        .txtPhone.BackColor = vbRed
        .txtPhone.SetFocus
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
     If Trim(.txtPrimaryEmail.Value) = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "Please enter a Primary Email Address.", vbOKOnly + 
      vbInformation, "PrimaryEmail"
        ValidateEntries = False
        .txtPrimaryEmail.BackColor = vbRed
        .txtPrimaryEmail.SetFocus
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    If Trim(.txtLocation.Value) = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "Please enter a Location.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, 
         "Location"
        ValidateEntries = False
        .txtLocation.BackColor = vbRed
        .txtLocation.SetFocus
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    If Trim(.cmbRequestedBy.Value) = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "Please select Requested By from drop-down.", vbOKOnly + 
        vbInformation, "RequestedBy"
        ValidateEntries = False
        .cmbRequestedBy.BackColor = vbRed
        .cmbRequestedBy.SetFocus
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    


End With



End Function
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Typically folks here like one question at a time...

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for your input, i will apply it for my next question

Comment: Not being focused is a reason for closing questions. Since this Q&A is a repository for future searchers, it works best if searchers find only what they are interested in.  [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73217540/edit) the post to focus it. Ask new questions about the parts you remove.